# How to open a text file from a URL in Selenium instead of downloading?

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium and trying to get the content of a text file without downloading it to the downloads folder.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    url = "http://somesite.com/file.st";
    driver.get(url);
}
```

the file is a plain text file of only JSON, no headers or markup.  Right now the above code, just downloads the file to the default chrome downloads folder.

Is it possible for Selenium to load the contents straight into a String instead of requiring the file being retrieved from disk?  I would like submit the retrieved JSON later to a form on another site using Selenium.

Comment: @Bᴜᴅɪ ,Why this question marked with `Python` tag?

Comment: @Andersson because it's Monday morning and this covfefe hasn't kicked in yet... thanks, I've updated the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, you can load the JSON file into a JSON Array object, then you can iterate over the JSON objects to get the data you need.

You will need to read the data from the url:

```
public static JSONArray readJsonFromURL(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String jsonText = readResponse(rd);
    // System.out.println("response: " + jsonText);
    JSONArray jsonData = new JSONArray(jsonText);
    is.close();
    return jsonData;

}
```

And a helper method to JSON to text:

```
public static String readResponse(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You can then create a new class for these methods, and then create a variable in your test to get the data:

```
responseText = JSONAPIResponse.readJsonFromURL(
            "http://somesite.com/file.st");
```

Comment: While the question specifically asks how to do this "in Selenium", I'm not sure if this is possible in selenium. Even if it was, I don't think it would be the right tool for this job. +1 for the non-selenium approach.

Comment: unfortunately this wont' work as it would require a separate connection to the server.  the file is specific to that particular session that I then need to pass to another page that will use it for this particular e2e testing.

Comment: I don't need to iterate through the data, just pass it along.  Right now the only option I've found is to load it from disk, which isn't browser agnostic.

Comment: I am confused on your question then, the data from the file will be stored in the "responseText" which you can then use throughout the rest of your test.  So in your test the first thing you would do is get the data from the url, then use that data in your other test, but it would all have to be done in the same test instance.

Comment: Here is the basic test.  Selenium opens a page, logs in, and then fills out some forms.  The user can then export this data to a JSON file via clicking on a link.  The test then loads the data from that file into another site to validate it.

If I use openStream() won't it open a new session to that URL?  This means the authentication tokens and data entered by the Selenium webdriver session would not be present and the link to the JSON would be invalid.

Comment: the driver.get(url) is independent of openStream, they do different things.

Comment: I do understand, this is why using openStream won't work for my case.  I need to do this all in the same session.  The data file is dependent on what the user enters after they login.

Comment: Will openstream using the existing connection/cookies already created by the Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: specifically the data file URL link won't work if initiated outside of the existing browser session.  for example, cutting and paste the link to a different browser or using it later will result in a 404.  its a specific security feature due to the sensitive nature of the site and its data.

Comment: so you call it when the data gets submitted, in my example, I was testing an existing API, but you should be able to call it in your test after the submit to get the data.